# Optimization failure in HoltWinters

Tags: r, forecasting

I am using `HoltWinters`to fit the exponential model on the data. The data shows trend as well as seasonal pattern.Getting the following error message:

`holt_output<-HoltWinters(data)`

`Error in HoltWinters(data) : optimization failure`

Not able to figure it out, why getting the above error.Would appreciate any kind of help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is about an issue w/ R, not an issue w/ statistics. Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) & we will migrate it for you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error message in R without a reproducible example.

Comment: Would you suggest me to move this question to Stack Overflow?

Comment: StackOverflow would be better, but you would be expected to [provide a minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The internal optimization in `HoltWinters()` ran into a numerical problem. That happens. I suggest you try `ets()` from the `forecast` package, which will also fit exponential smoothing models, albeit in a state space framework.

`ets()` will (attempt to) automatically choose the best model form, but if you insist on having an additive level-and-trend model, you can call `ets(y=data,model="AAN")`. See `?ets`.

Comment: thanks for the response. The reason why I am using `HoltWinters()` is that, it is giving better result that `ets()` ( MAPE is less ). Is there a way to get the same model in `ets()` suggested by `HoltWinters()` ?

Comment: You can't get the *exact* same model, but the difference should usually be minor. If the MAPE (out-of-sample, right? in-sample goodness of fit is no indicator of forecasting performance) differs systematically by a nontrivial amount between `ets(data,model="AAN")` and `HoltWinters(data)`, then something is strange.